# import modules from folder (Python)

Tags: python, function, import, directory

I have a python file "a.py", a folder named folder and in the folder it has "b.py".

a.py has the code:

```
from folder.b import *
function()
```

It says:

> NameError: name 'function' is not defined

It is defined.

Why?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py`'s  in the folders?

Comment: Yes I have `__init__` file in the folder

Comment: @Ofek.T. could you show what is in `b.py` and your dicrectory structure?

Comment: It's a very very very long code, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use `folder.b`? If not: You can add your folder name `folder` to system path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(your_folder_containing_b.py)
```

And change a.py to:

```
from b import *
```

A less straight forward way is to change current working directory to `folder` and then `from b import *`

```
import os
os.chdir(your_folder_containing_b.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to define PYTHONPATH properly, making sure that it contains `folder`'s parent folder.